# Calculate daily average including zero in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset of patients visiting several categories(SPECIALISM) of a hospital. A visit lasts a couple of hours each day. Each row in my dataset represents an hour that they are present for a certain hospital specialism.

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx97z.jpg)

I want to calculate for each hour of the day, the number of patients that are present on average, per specialism, I used the following code (measure):

```
daggem = AVERAGEX(values('Date'[Date]),[distinctpat])
```

with distinctpat being a distinct count of patient IDs

This gives me almost the desired result, but the tales of the graph are too heavy (it shows an average of 1 patient during the night, but this 1 patient was there only on 1 specific day, normally it is zero. But the average, as I calculated, it does not include all other nights when there were zero patients. So I would like to obtain an average that is much lower (and more correct)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHZEL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an extra table with all the days and times. Based on the reports, you will be able to find the hours without visits

Here is an example of how to create a Date table with hours; Add relationship and use in calculation.

```
DatesWithHours = 
var Dates = CALENDAR("2021-01-01 00:00:00", "2021-01-03 00:00:00")
var DatesHour =
GENERATE(Dates, (ADDCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(1,12,1),"Hours", [Date] + TIME([Value],0,0))))
return
DatesHour
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem with AVERAGEX, it ignores blanks. Try a simple division instead.

```
daggem =
DIVIDE (
    COUNTROWS ( TargetTable ),
    COUNTROWS ( Dates )
)
```